# how to create wordpress updatble plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Please let me know how can I create an updateable plugin. so users can update it when plugin update available.
I know how to create a plugin but I don't know how to provide new updates . and what update related function I need to add in my first version.

Answer (score 0):

to create updates for your plugins just change its version at the beginning of the code and when you upload your changes in the wordpress directory all users will automatically receive the information that is out of date.

To learn more about creating plugins go to the documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

If you have any other questions let me know here, I will try to help you :)